# How to make a desktop application from the existing web application code

Tags: javascript, web, air, desktop-application

Suppose I have a simple web application to browse pictures. The server-side provides REST APIs to access pictures in the server file system. The client-side calls the APIs to get the pictures and display them in the browser.

Suppose, both server and client-side are coded in `JavaScript`. Is there any easy way to make a *desktop* application from all this JavaScript code ?

I remember `Adobe Air` does sometihng similar but I would prefer an open-source alternative.

Comment: Can't you just use Tomcat and Apache?

Comment: You mean making it an application that doesn't use the browser? If that's not what you mean, why not just bundle it with a shell script that runs the server and opens the browser?

Answer (score 1):

RESTful APIs are for transferring data from one point to another. Since your data is designed to transfer data from a server to a client, combining both blocks of code into a single desktop app doesn't really make sense.

As for the client-side code, there is a handy SDK I've heard of called [**TideSDK**](http://www.tidesdk.org/). I don't know too much about it, but it allows you to create cross-platform desktop apps from HTML, CSS, and JS. You could likely reuse your client-side code in with this SDK to make a desktop app.